# Simplificar do-while y problema con char en do-while (programación en C)

Tags: c, codeblocks

Estoy realizando un programa en el que hay que introducir una circunferencia (por su centro y su radio) y un punto en un plano cartesiano, el programa calcula si el punto está fuera, dentro o pertenece a la circunferencia. Este es el código que he logrado hacer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int ubicacionpuntocircunferencia(float Cx, float Cy, float rad, float Px, float Py);

int main()
{
    float Cx, Cy, rad, Px, Py;
    int resul;
    char masptos;
    do{
        printf("\nIntroduzca la abscisa (x) del centro de la circunferencia [-255,255]: ");
        scanf("%f", &Cx);}
    while(Cx<-255 || Cx>255);
    do{
        printf("\nIntroduzca la ordenada (y) del centro de la circunferencia [-255,255]: ");
        scanf("%f", &Cy);}
    while(Cy<-255 || Cy>255);
    do{
        printf("\nIntroduzca el radio de la circunferencia (rad > 0): ");
        scanf("%f", &rad);}
    while(rad<=0);
    do{
        do{
            printf("\nIntroduzca la abscisa (x) del punto [-255,255]: ");
            scanf("%f", &Px);}
        while(Px<-255 || Px>255);
        do{
            printf("\nIntroduzca la ordenada (y) del punto [-255,255]: ");
            scanf("%f", &Py);}
        while(Py<-255 || Py>255);
        resul = ubicacionpuntocircunferencia(Cx,Cy,rad,Px,Py);
        if(resul == 1)
            printf("\nEl punto esta dentro de la cincurferencia");
        else
            {if(resul == 0)
                printf("\nEl punto pertenece a la circunferencia");
            else
                printf("\nEl punto esta fuera de la circunferencia");
            }
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nIntroducir mas puntos? (S/n): ");
        scanf("%c", &masptos);}
    while(masptos == 'S' || masptos == 's');
    return 0;
}
    
int ubicacionpuntocircunferencia(float Cx, float Cy, float rad, float Px, float Py)
    {
        float resultado,rad_cuad;
        resultado = pow(Px-Cx,2) + pow(Py-Cy,2);
        rad_cuad = pow(rad,2);
        if(resultado < rad_cuad)
            return 1;
        else
            {if(resultado == rad_cuad)
                return 0;
            else
                return -1;}
    }
```

Quisiera saber si se podrían simplificar o eliminar algunos do-whiles para que el código no sea tan largo. También, después de calcular la posición del punto respecto a la circunferencia, el programa no deja introducir el carácter en el caso de que se quiera seguir introduciendo más puntos ¿qué error que hay ahí?

Comment: Hombre, viendo que los datos se tienen que mantener en el mismo rango siempre, si quieres simplificarlo, puedes pasar la lectura de el dato a una funcion, entonces tu solo le pasas el texto y el puntero a la variable.

Comment: @Pablochaches ¿Cómo resolvería el bucle para poder introducir más puntos?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el `\n` se queda en *stdin* despues de que metes los datos. Eso parece que ya lo sabes, por algo tendras el `fflush(stdin);`. Pasa que esta no es una forma estandar, en algunos lados funciona, en otros no, y en otros no compila directamente. Yo lo que haria seria lo siguiente: `scanf("%*c%c", &masptos);` El `%*c` es un caracter que lee, pero por el `*` lo ignora. Asi ignoras el `\n` y lees lo que te dio el usuario. Siempre prueba buscar soluciones con las herramientas estandar, asi tu codigo funcionara en todos lados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma de simplificar un código es extraer aquello que es repetitivo y ponerlo dentro de una función.

¿Qué es repetitivo dentro de tu código? Imprimes un mensaje, ingresas un valor y lo validas dentro de un rango.

Eso puedes ponerlo dentro de una función así:

```
float get_value(char* message, float lim_inf, float lim_sup) {
    float valor;
    do {
        printf(message);
        scanf("%f%*c", &valor);
    } while (valor < lim_inf || valor > lim_sup);
    return valor;       
}
```

Y ahora reemplazas todas esos `do ... while` con:

```
Cx = get_value("\nIntroduzca la abscisa (x) del centro de la circunferencia [-255,255]: ", -255, 255);
Cy = get_value("\nIntroduzca la ordenada (y) del centro de la circunferencia [-255,255]: ", -255, 255);
rad = get_value("\nIntroduzca el radio de la circunferencia (rad > 0): ", 1, 255);
do{
    Px = get_value("\nIntroduzca la abscisa (x) del punto [-255,255]: ", -255, 255);
    Py = get_value("\nIntroduzca la ordenada (y) del punto [-255,255]: ", -255, 255);
...
}
```